# Get an open position ticket in MQL5

Tags: mql5

I want to get the ticket number immediately after opening the position.

**The output of this code is zero:**

```
bool r = trade.Buy(0.1, Symbol(), 0, 0, 0); 
   
   if(r) 
   {            
      position_Info.SelectByIndex(0);
      Alert(position_Info.Ticket());      
   }
```

**But if I add a delay command, the output will be displayed correctly:**

```
bool r = trade.Buy(0.1, Symbol(), 0, 0, 0); 
   
   if(r) 
   {      
      Sleep(2000); // <=======================HERE
      position_Info.SelectByIndex(0);
      Alert(position_Info.Ticket());      
   }
```

**How can I do this without adding a delay command?**

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation.

Successful completion of the [Buy](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/standardlibrary/tradeclasses/ctrade/ctradebuy) method does not always mean successful execution of the trade operation. It is necessary to check the result of trade request (trade server return code) using [ResultRetcode()](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/standardlibrary/tradeclasses/ctrade/ctraderesultretcode) and value returned by [ResultDeal()](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/standardlibrary/tradeclasses/ctrade/ctraderesultdeal).

```
ulong  ResultDeal() const
```

Return Value = Deal ticket if the deal is executed.

The following code example has been tested and confirmed as working:

```
#property strict

#include <Trade\Trade.mqh>
#include <Trade\SymbolInfo.mqh>
#include <Trade\PositionInfo.mqh>

CTrade   trade;
CPositionInfo position_Info;

datetime TimeBar;

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Initialization function of the expert                            |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
{
return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| "Tick" event handler function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
{
   if(TimeBar==iTime(_Symbol,_Period,0))
   {
   return;
   }

   if(TimeBar==0)
   {
      bool res = trade.Buy(0.1, Symbol(), 0, 0, 0); 
      if(res && trade.ResultRetcode()==TRADE_RETCODE_DONE) Print(trade.ResultDeal());
      TimeBar=iTime(_Symbol,_Period,0);
   return;
   }

   TimeBar=iTime(_Symbol,_Period,0);
return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i use if(trade.ResultRetcode() == TRADE_RETCODE_DONE) Alert("ResultDeal=", trade.ResultDeal()); but trade.ResultDeal() is still 0

Comment: I've expanded my answer with full code example which I've checked and confirmed is working

Comment: How can I use your code in OnInit method?

Comment: In your code the output is still 0.

Comment: I've tested this code on MT5 and the output is not 0, the ticket number is returned